# Transfer files from one RPi to another (via network)

Tags: pi-3, pi-4, headless, terminal, data-transfer

I have two Raspberry Pis, one a 3 running Raspbian Stretch, the other a 4 running Raspbian Bullseye, both headless.

I have need to transfer files from the 3 to the 4 (always in that direction) over the network (copying to/from USB is not ideal).

How would I go about copying files via CLI from one Pi to the other?  To start with / to test it'll just be one at a time specified via the command line.  It doesn't matter to me whether it's pushed from the 3 or pulled from the 4.

I connect to them both via SSH using Putty from my Windows PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to transfer files from one RPi to another; `scp` is one way, `rsync` is another. If it's a file transfer you need to do regularly, you can *automate* this using `rsync`, and run it as a `cron` job. But in keeping with your question to do it from the command line, I'd suggest this:

```bash
$ scp -3 pi@raspberrypi3b:/home/pi/test_file.txt pi@raspberrypi4b:/home/pi
```

What's going on here?

This one-liner xfers the file `/home/pi/test_file.txt` **from** a user account named `pi` on a host named `raspberrypi3b` **to** a user account named `pi` on a host named `raspberrypi4b`. The `-3` option causes the file transfer to go ***through*** your local host (the computer from which you have entered the above command).

**If** you have the SSH key exchange set up between `raspberrypi3b` and `raspberrypi4b`, you should be able to copy *directly*; i.e. the `-3` option is no longer needed.

Comment: @Midavalo: Take your time - no worries.

Comment: After fixing the other issues I discovered, I managed to get this to work.  I had to use IP address rather than hostname, but that's fine for now.  Thanks.

Comment: @Midavalo: Yeah - hostnames ought to work if you've got [Avahi/mDNS](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/remote-access.html#resolving-raspberrypi-local-with-mdns) working properly. There's [another answer here that may be useful in overcoming the need to use IP addresses instead of hostnames.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/138482/83790)

Answer (score 2):

since you've set up `ssh` on both, you can just use `scp`

So, either `ssh` into the 3, then something like

```
scp path-on-3/file user@pi4host:path-on-4/file
```

or, conversely, `ssh` into the 4 and

```
scp user@pi3host:path-on-3/file ./path-on-4/file ...
```

obviously `user` `path-on-3` `path-on-4` `file` `pi3host` and `pi4host` are placeholders in the commands above and you would have to determine actual values